# In Android Studio (IntelliJ), how do I access the Android Manifest as it displays in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to display [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8U2P.jpg), but I can only find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LmiB.jpg). I am running the latest updates for the SDK and ADT.  I would like to access the Manifest, Application, Permissions, Instrumentation, and AndroidManifest.xml tabs so I can more easily edit the Manifest but seem to only find these tabs in eclipse. Surely IntelliJ has a similar option?

Comment: Why do you want the GUI access? Just curios to know.

Comment: I need to access the Application Attributes so that I can make my application debuggable. I do not know any XML and I am learning it through an android application class online but the class uses Eclipse and I cannot get my Eclipse to run with the current update to 12.0.1 or whatever it is. Now I guess I need to take an XML course to understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio currently doesn't have this option. You have to use pure XML. Once you get used to it, it is actually much better than using GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not realize that Android Studio lacked this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate -> file -> type AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thank you but I also do not know how to display the Android Manifest as it displays in Eclipse. I would like to access the Manifest, Application, Permissions, Instrumentation, and AndroidManifest.xml tabs so I can more easily edit the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

This is the XML Code you need to make your android app debuggable.

In your application tag add an attribute like this

```
    <application
        .
        .
        .
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
```

However you **should avoid** hardcoding debuggable tag and let Android Studio assign this value to your debug and release builds automatically.